# can mathematica plot graph/visualize rotation matrices

Tags: plotting

just wondering is there any example online
that show plotting of 3d rotation matrices
like in the picture below ([source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uWk8.png))

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5774073

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the documentation examples for [**RotationMatrix**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RotationMatrix.html) and [**RotationTransform**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RotationTransform.html). Then the following Demonstrations give you basically code you need:

- [**Euler Angles**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EulerAngles/)
- [**Euler Angles: Precession, Nutation, and Spin**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EulerAnglesPrecessionNutationAndSpin/)
- [**Understanding 3D Rotation**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Understanding3DRotation/)
- [**Euler Angles for Space Shuttle**](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EulerAnglesForSpaceShuttle/)

Screenshot of the first one:

[image: test]

Comment: thanks, this is just what I'm looking for...